# Coffescript classes and undescore templates in separate files but compiled into single js and html file in WebStrom

Tags: html, class, templates, coffeescript, webstorm

I am developping an html5 project with custom scripts.
Actually I am using CoffeeScript because I like its syntax more thent JS.
I am also using underscore templates defined like `<script type="text/template"  id="manager-template">`
I am using WebStorm as IDE.

Is there any easy way I can

1. Have CoffeeScript  classes in separate files but I want them to be compiled into a single js file
2. Have templates in separate files but I want them to be compoled into single index.htlm file

Preferably to have this "on fly" in WebStorm

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575260/join-multiple-coffeescript-files-into-one-file-multiple-subdirectories for possible solutions for .coffee

Comment: note that you can configure any tool/shell script as a file watcher in WebStorm to watch your files and transpile data on-the-fly